# Volume of region bounded by two curves revolved around x-axis

Tags: calculus, integration

$f(x) = x^2 - 4x + 5$ and $g(x) = 1/2$ and $x = 1$ and $x = 3$

I found the area from 1 to 3 of the region bounded by these functions: [image: link]

I ended up with $\int_1^3 (x^2-4x+9/2)dx$. I am trying to figure out how to evaluate the integral that will give the volume of the solid generated by revolving the region around the x-axis. Any help on how to set up this problem would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You have to integrate $\pi f(x)^2 -\pi \cdot (1/2)^2$ for $x$ from 1 to 3. [Look up "volume by washers" method or something similar]

Answer (score 1):

$\int_1^3 \pi(x^2-4x+9/2)^2dx$. Also called the washer method

Comment: If you type \pi it will render as $\pi$.  Also, you've made a bit of a mistake.  What should be inside the integral is $\pi (R^{2}-r^{2})$.  You cannot bring the $\frac{1}{2}=r$ in as you did.  It should be $(x^2-4x+5)^2-\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2}$.  Effectively what you have is $\pi(R-r)^2$.

Comment: As Travis remarks, this answer as it stands is incorrect.